# Wicket 7 log in with remember me checkbox

Tags: session, authentication, wicket

I am trying to understand the "remember me" functionality in the Wicket Login page.

I have a SignIn form in my SignIn page and I add a checkbox in the form. 
By default the "remember me" function is enabled in the model according to [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-auth-roles/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authentication/panel/SignInPanel.java). 
So, what should I do with my checkbox onSubmit? - If my checkbox is not checked then get the list of cookies and clear it?

Obviously the user should be able to auto-login after the end of the session..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IAuthenticationStrategy` to save the username and the password into an encrypted cookie. See [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/7544d4d3113daad60a1aa3e2d9add171305c8494/wicket-auth-roles/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/authroles/authentication/panel/SignInPanel.java#L300-L309)

```
IAuthenticationStrategy strategy = getApplication().getSecuritySettings()
            .getAuthenticationStrategy();

        if (signIn(getUsername(), getPassword()))
        {
            if (rememberMe == true)
            {
                strategy.save(username, password);
            }
            else
            {
                strategy.remove();
            }

            onSignInSucceeded();
        }
```